# Can't Execute $ time rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Example by Michael Hartl but I got stuck.

Everytime I try to run the following test I got an error:

```
time rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

My error:

```
/home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/i/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

real    0m0.752s
user    0m0.699s
sys 0m0.044s
```

static_pages_spec.rb :

```
require 'spec_helper'
 
describe "StaticPages" do
 
  describe "Home page" do
    it "It should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
          visit '/static_pages/home'
          expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
        end
  end
 
describe "Help page" do
    it "It should have the content 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      expect(page).to have_content('Help')
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
          visit '/static_pages/help'
          expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
        end
  end
 
describe "About page" do
    it "It should have the content 'About Us'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
    end
  end
    it "should have the right title" do
          visit '/static_pages/about'
          expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
        end
describe "Contact" do
    it "It should have the content 'Contact'" do
      visit '/static_pages/contact'
      expect(page).to have_content('Contact')
    end
  end
    it "should have the right title" do
          visit '/static_pages/contact'
          expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
        end
 
end
```

### Gemfile: ## http://pastebin.com/1RhbaCiK

**OS**: Ubuntu 14.04

I've been searching for solution, but have not found one. Please keep in mind that I'm new to Ruby on Rails and web development.

Comment: Please show `spec_helper.rb`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WKG7QBgT
Here is it

Comment: Yes, always from there

Comment: I tried to fix that problem , and got one more. Now if I run that command, I get:

:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ time rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
/home/i/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/guard-spork-1.5.0/lib/guard/spork.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- guard/guard (LoadError)

Comment: The solution in answer below. 
Updating gem 'guard-spork' - from  '1.5.0' to '2.1.0' in:
**Gemfile** and **Gemfile.lock**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is saying:

```
cannot load such file -- /home/i/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
```

which means RSpec can't find the spec. I see you have `spec` twice in the file path: `../sample_app/spec/spec/..`.

You should keep your specs under the `spec` directory of your Rails app. So, the path should be: `/sample_app/spec/` like this. Fix that and try again. It should work.

### Update

So, after running your code locally, I found the issue. There was a gem dependency issue with gem `guard-spork`.

You just need to upgrade this gem. In your `Gemfile`:

Change `gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'` to `gem 'guard-spork', '2.1.0'`

Then, `bundle install`

And, then run `time rspec`

Everything will run smoothly :-)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87146/discussion-on-answer-by-k-m-rakibul-islam-cant-execute-time-rspec-spec-reques).